# Как задать формат пикселей в изображении?

Tags: c#

Хочу поставить формат пикселей Format8bppIndexed. Выдает ошибку.

**{"Невозможно создать объект графики из изображения, имеющего индексированный формат пикселей."}**

```
 var recHeight = Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * 0.23);
            var recWidth = Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * 0.23);

            //var posH = Convert.ToInt32((img.Height - recHeight) / 2 + recHeight);
            var posH = Convert.ToInt32((img.Height - recHeight) / 2);
            var posW = Convert.ToInt32(((img.Width - recWidth) / 2));

            //Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(posH, posW, recWidth, recHeight);
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(posW, posH, recWidth, recHeight);


            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(recWidth, recHeight,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            using (Graphics gph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                gph.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), rec, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            return bmp;
```

Comment: А палитра где? 8-битное изображение предполагает наличие палитры (таблицы цветов от 0 до 255). Используйте другую перезагрузку - с палитрой.

Comment: @nick_n_a можете ткнуть)?

Comment: Похоже нету. Остается вариант через Stream.

Comment: Сперва создайте изображение с простым `PixelFormat`, скажем, `Format24bppRgb`. Для него создайте `Graphics`, нарисуйте что необходимо. После чего [конвертируйте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698004/5045688) изображение в индексированное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET (если конкретно то в GDI+) очень ограниченная поддержка изображений с индексированным форматом пикселей. На них нельзя рисовать, или вызывать `SetPixel`. Палитру придется создавать вручную. Ниже пример кода, который создает изображение с форматом пикселей `Format8bppIndexed`:

```
// создаем полноценный битмап
var bmp32 = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp32))
{
    g.Clear(Color.Black);
    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, 10, 10, 80, 80);
}

// создаем битмап с палитрой
var bmp8 = new Bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
var palette = bmp8.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256;  i++)
{
    // заполняем палитру, для простоты это будут все оттенки серого
    palette.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
}
// это не просто так, обязательно нужна эта строка
bmp8.Palette = palette;

var data = bmp8.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
var bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        // берем пиксель с основного 32битного битмапа
        var color = bmp32.GetPixel(x, y);
        // ищем цвет в палитре 8битного битмапа
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < palette.Entries.Length; i++)
            if (palette.Entries[i] == color)
            {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        if (index == -1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot find color in palette");
        // записываем индекс цвета в палитре напрямую в изображение
        bytes[y * data.Stride + x] = (byte)index;
    }

Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);
bmp8.UnlockBits(data);

bmp8.Save("1.gif");
```